# PHP SimpleXML - One-line solution lookup a key; find its parent in XML file?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My goal is: first, find a specific key in an XML file. Second, return the parent of the key. In the code example below, the key is a filename.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $inputXML = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");

    $myProject = lookupProject($inputXML, "file1");
    echo $myProject->projectname; //print the name of the project containing <filename>"file1"</filename>
    echo "\n";

    /*
     Goal: return the <project> that is the parent of <filename>$input_filename</filename>
     Assume: a <filename> appears in at most one <project> subtree.
     */
    function lookupProject($myXML, $input_filename)  
    {
        foreach($myXML->project as $curr_project) //notice I don't mention the root <projects></projects>
        {
            foreach($curr_project->filename as $curr_filename)
            {
                if ($curr_filename == $input_filename) 
                {
                    return $curr_project; 
                }
            }
        }
        return null; //if not found, return null
    }  
?>
```

**Example data file, data.xml**

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <projectname>project1</projectname>
        <filename>file1</filename>
        <filename>file2</filename>
    </project>
    <project>
        <projectname>project2</projectname>
        <filename>file3</filename>
    </project>
</projects>
```

If we have a more complex XML structure with many levels of subtrees, finding the parent of file1 could require lots of foreach() loops. Is there a SimpleXML command that would abstract away the loops that appear in lookupProject?

tl;dr is there a short/elegant (one-line?) solution that implements lookupProject()?

Note that this is [homework](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/cs242sp12/Assignment+2.0), but the above question is not at all the crux of the homework problem. I'm done with the homework assignment, but knowing the answer to the above question would help me to make my solution more elegant.

Comment: +1 for declaring this as homework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more appropriate term for "key" would be "TextNode value". You are looking for

- [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath` — Runs XPath query on XML data](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

In your case this [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html) query will give the projectname element

```
/projects/project[filename="file1"]/projectname
```

Since this is tagged homework, I'll leave it up to you to figure out the necessary PHP code.

Comment: Gordon--this is fantastic, thanks! I voted up your answer.

I'll post here if I have any trouble, but I think I see how to implement this with xpath,

Comment: Here's how I solved it:

    `function lookupProjectElegant($myXML, $input_filename) 
    {
        $queryString = '/projects/project[filename="' . $input_filename . '"]';
        $result = $myXML->xpath($queryString);
        return $result[0]; 
    }`

Comment: Annoyingly, I wasn't able to format the newlines in this comment...hope it's not too confusing. Let me know if you know how to do newlines in comments :)

Comment: @solvingPuzzles I'd probably would have used sprintf because I find that more readable but apart from that, this is how I would have done it, too. Good job. Re comments: you cannot have newlines in here.

Comment: @solvingPuzzles - FYI, you can always add your own answer and accept someone else's.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice way of getting a parent of an XML node by subclassing SimpleXML - see my [code here](https://github.com/halfer/Meshing/blob/master/lib/Meshing/Schema/Element.php#L221) - not my idea though; found it on php.net, I believe.